# What computer program can calculate Kemeny-Snell's median?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, math-software

Unfortunately, I didn't find any computer realization for computing Kemeny-Snell's median.

Comment: What is Kemeny-Snells median? Yoy should give a reference!

Comment: Sorry. Kemeny-Snell's median deals with rankings. It makes possible to get collective ranking from a number of individuals rankings, i.e. to get the "aggregation" answer on some measurements in order scale.

Comment: [1] Mathematical models in the social sciences -- John G. Kemeny and J. Laurie Snell, 1972.

Comment: Kemeny's distance between rankings intoduced by next axiomatic way. Axiom1: d(A,B)>0 or iff A=B d(A,B)=0.

Axiom2: d(A,B)=d(B,A).

Axiom3: d(A,B)+d(B,C) less or equal d(A,C).

Axiom4: minimum distance is 1.

Theorem: For axioms 1-4 there is only one way to determine such metric d: d(A,B)=1/2\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}-b{ij}|.

Then median is defined as point B for which \sum_{i=1}^m d(A_i, B) is the minimum.

Comment: What about this implementation? http://www.nr.com/whp/ky/kemenyyoung.html

Comment: Wow, it looks like what i need!
Great thanks, Alex Kemper!

Comment: @AxelKemper, does Kemeny–Young method allow sharing places for objects?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [C++ Program](http://www.nr.com/whp/ky/kemenyyoung.html) for calculating the Kemeny-Young ordering, written by William H. Press of University of Texas. Pointed out by Axel Kemper in the comments.

Comment: user98130, Kemeny-Snell's median = Kemeny-Young ordering?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested I discovered an R package to compute Kemeny-Snell median ranking. It is called ConsRank.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ConsRank/index.html